# Drag And Drop Directiv in AngularJS moving cards

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I use this directiv : http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/types

I have problem to with moving cards, when i move cards higher is ok, if the cards give less the problem starts.

i did this feature :

```
if ($scope.movingItem.indeksList == index) {
        console.log('qrwa')
        $scope.lists[$scope.movingItem.indeksList].cards.splice($scope.movingItem.IndexCard +1, 1);
        $scope.lists[index].cards = external[index].cards;
    } else {
        console.log('qrwa2')
        $scope.lists[$scope.movingItem.indeksList].cards.splice($scope.movingItem.IndexCard, 1);
        $scope.lists[index].cards = external[index].cards;
    }
```

If I do the movement in the same list and i move card higher is ok then must be perform:

```
$scope.lists[$scope.movingItem.indeksList].cards.splice($scope.movingItem.IndexCard +1, 1);
```

When from up to down must be perform :

```
$scope.lists[$scope.movingItem.indeksList].cards.splice($scope.movingItem.IndexCard, 1);
```

And here is problem I cant get $index on which place I drop card to make If that I move card lower make this perform, If higer make this perform...

Here is whole project: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/BVF0KxPrWiCeGDXVpQDV?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
$scope.dropCallback = function (index, item, external) {
  $scope.lists[$scope.movingItem.indeksList].cards.splice($scope.movingItem.IndexCard, 1);
  $scope.lists[index].cards = external[index].cards;

  console.log($scope.lists[index].cards)

  return item;
};
```

The watcher is not neccesary in this case, because you are getting informed of changes by the `dropCallback` function itself.

Your job is simply to remove the item at the index, like you did. Regardless of the moving direction.

**EDIT**

Here is [the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sln5iCh0jojS4eylyC72?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to use `dropCallback` just to move items around in the list. You can use `dnd-moved="item.cards.splice($index, 1)"` as shown in the [demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/types).

Check out update version of your code:

```js
angular.module("app", ["dndLists"]).controller("c1", function($scope){
  $scope.title ="drag and drop";
  
  $scope.lists = [ 
   {
     id: 2, 
     name: "list2", 
     cards: [
       {  name: "card1"},
       {  name: "card2"},
       {  name: "card3"},
       {  name: "card4"}, 
       {  name: "card5"}
     ]
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: "list3", 
     cards: [
      {  name: "card1"},
      {  name: "card2"},
      {  name: "card3"},
      {  name: "card4"}, 
      {  name: "card5"}
    ]
  }
  ];
    

 $scope.logEvent = function (indeksList, IndexCard) {
  $scope.movingItem = {
   indeksList: indeksList,
   IndexCard: IndexCard
  }
 };
 
 $scope.dropCallback = function (index, item, external) {
  return item;
 };
  
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

  .tilt {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  }


  .column {
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .portlet {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
  .portlet-header {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }
  .portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  .portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 50px;
  }





/* <BEGIN> For OS X */

*:focus {
 outline: none;
}

html {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

/* <END> For OS X */

body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background-color: #0375AB;
}

#wrapper, #topbar-inner {
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#topbar {
 background-color: #036492;
}

#topbar-inner {
 height: 42px;
 position: relative;
}

#topbar #nav {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 background: yellow;
}

#topbar #logo {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 8px;
 text-align: center;
}

#topbar #login {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 10px;
}

#topbar #logo h1 {
 margin: 0;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#topbar #logo h1:hover {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
 cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

#tasks {
 width: 260px;
 padding: 7px;
 background-color: #E2E4E6;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#tasks h3 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#tasks ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#tasks li {
 padding: 5px 8px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

#tasks li i {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

#tasks li i:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#tasks li i.fa-trash-o {
 color: #888;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#tasks input[type=text] {
 margin: 0;
 width: 244px;
 padding: 5px 8px;
 border-width: 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-login {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #448DAF;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.5" data-semver="1.6.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-drag-and-drop-lists@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="c1">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
      <li ng-repeat="item in lists">
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
          <div id="tasks">
            {{item.name}}

            <ul dnd-list="item.cards" dnd-drop="dropCallback($index, item, lists)">
              <li ng-repeat="card in item.cards" 
                  dnd-draggable="card" 
                  dnd-dragstart="logEvent($parent.$index, $index)"
                  dnd-moved="item.cards.splice($index, 1)"
                  dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
                  ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}" 
                  dnd-effect-allowed="move">
                {{card.name}}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form ng-submit="addTask(item._id, newTask, $index)">
              <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="add a new task" required />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

You can find Plunker project [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6v1R7s5aCcGHbewOj9oH?p=preview).